Ошибка velocity маинкрафт 1.16.5
я пытаюсь создать связку маинкрафт серверов через velocity, но выдаёт ошибку:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/velocityp
    owered/proxy/Velocity has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Run
    time (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes
     class file versions up to 52.0
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)your text
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .```



has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Run time - требуется перевод?
